# Check if a Debian package is installed from Python

Tags: python, debian

Is there an elegant and more Python-like way to check if a package is installed on Debian?

In a bash script, I'd do:

```
dpkg -s packagename | grep Status
```

Suggestions to do the same in a Python script?

Answer (score 26):

This is a pythonic way:

```
import apt
cache = apt.Cache()
if cache['package-name'].is_installed:
    print "YES it's installed"
else:
    print "NO it's NOT installed"
```

Comment: You would get a key error in the case of a package not installed. There's another way to do it that would catch this and provide a neater output if the package is not found. I'll post this as a comment to the OP.

Comment: How to also install the package: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537390/how-to-install-a-package-using-the-python-apt-api

Answer (score 8):

A slightly nicer, hopefully idiomatic version of your bash example:

```
import os, subprocess
devnull = open(os.devnull,"w")
retval = subprocess.call(["dpkg","-s","coreutils"],stdout=devnull,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
devnull.close()
if retval != 0:
    print "Package coreutils not installed."
```

Comment: This is wrong. `dpkg -s` will also return successfully (with a zero exit) if a package is in the state `deinstall ok config-files`, i.e. the package is *not* installed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking for the existence of a package that installs a Python module, you can test for this from within a dependent Python script - try to import it and see if you get an exception:

```
import sys
try:
    import maybe
except ImportError:
    print "Sorry, must install the maybe package to run this program."
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: These aren't the packages the OP is looking for. Python packages and Debian's package manager's packages are (largely) different things. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg

Comment: Well, the OP did ask if there was a way from within a Python script, so I don't think it was too far a leap to think he was looking for a way to detect a Python module dependency.  Still, point taken, I hope I've more properly qualified my answer.

Comment: Google sent me here in search of this answer, so it is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is some code that would give you a neat way to display if the package is installed or not (without triggering a messy error message on the screen). This works in Python 3 only, though.

```py
import apt
cache = apt.Cache()
cache.open()

response = "Package Installed."
try:
    cache['notapkg'].is_installed
except KeyError:
    response = "Package Not Installed."

print(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`commands`](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html). It's very useful for running things on the command line and getting the status.

Otherwise, I'm sure there is some library that will let you interact with apt. [python-apt](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/tutorials/apt-get.html) might work but it's a bit raw. Just capturing the command line seems easier.

Answer (score 1):

I needed a cross-platform compatible solution so I ended up using [which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Which_(Unix)).

```
import subprocess
retval = subprocess.call(["which", "packagename"])
if retval != 0:
    print("Packagename not installed!")
```

Although it's not as pythonic as the above answers it does work on most platforms.

Comment: Your soljution might work with packages such as wget, but not with packages such as coreutils

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the previous answers, this works nicely for both Python 2 and Python 3 and avoids try/catch for the key error:

```
import apt
package = 'foo' # insert your package name here
cache = apt.Cache()
package_installed = False

if package in cache:
    package_installed = cache[package].is_installed
```

Comment: In conda base environment (with Anaconda3) `import apt` gives the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt'`. What would be the most proper solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt. Searched every corner in the Internet but couldn't find it.
But finally after some Experiments ***I DID IT!!***.

- Code:

1. `import os`
2. `packagename = "figlet" # Type in your package name`
3. `os.system("dpkg -s "+packagename" | grep Status")`

To type in any terminal using python codes:

- Code:

1. `import os`
2. `os.system("YOUR TERMINAL COMMAND HERE")`

Comment: Unless there's a fringe case, there's no reason to use grep. Just read the exit code.

`def test_dpkgInstalled(packageName):
    return (os.system("dpkg -s " + packageName + "> /dev/null 2>&1")) == 0`