# How to install a package using the python-apt API

Tags: python, apt

I'm quite a newbie when it comes to Python, thus I beg foregiveness beforehand :). That said, I'm trying to make a script that, among other things, installs some Linux packages. First I tried to use subopen as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481943/using-apt-get-install-xxx-inside-python-script). While this can eventually work, I stumbled upon the [python-apt API](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/) and since I'm not a big fan or re-inventing the wheel, I decided to give a try.

Problem comes when trying to find examples/tutorials on installing a package using python-apt. Searching the documentation I found the [PackageManager](http://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/apt_pkg.html#apt_pkg.PackageManager) class that has some methods to install a package. I tried some simple code to get this working:

```
apt_pkg.PackageManager.install("python")
```

This does not seem to work that easily, the install method expects apt_pkg.PackageManager instead of a plain String. Thus, looking a bit more, [I found this example](http://mancoosi.org/~abate/aptget-installation-plan) that looks promising, but I'm a bit reluctant to use since I don't really understand some of what is happening there.

Then, has anyone tried to install a package using python-apt or should I go for using plain-old subopen style?

Thanks!

Comment: python-apt seems discontinued, most of the links no longer work and according to pypi the package hasn't seen an update since it's release in 2012

Comment: @DBX12 I think it's just the pypi package that isn't being maintained. A much newer version is in the Debian repos. For py2 (https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python-apt) or (separate package) for py3 (https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python3-apt).

Comment: Just the check if already installed instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387961/check-if-a-debian-package-is-installed-from-python

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's recommended to use the `apt` module from the `python-apt` Debian package.  This is a higher level wrapper around the underlying C/C++ `libapt-xxx` libraries and has a Pythonic interface.

Here's an example script which will install the `libjs-yui-doc` package:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# aptinstall.py

import apt
import sys

pkg_name = "libjs-yui-doc"

cache = apt.cache.Cache()
cache.update()
cache.open()

pkg = cache[pkg_name]
if pkg.is_installed:
    print "{pkg_name} already installed".format(pkg_name=pkg_name)
else:
    pkg.mark_install()

    try:
        cache.commit()
    except Exception, arg:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Sorry, package installation failed [{err}]".format(err=str(arg))
```

As with the use of `apt-get`, this must be run with superuser privileges to access and modify the APT cache.

```
$ sudo ./aptinstall.py
```

If you're attempting a package install as part of a larger script, it's probably a good idea to only raise to root privileges for the minimal time required.

You can find a small example in the `/usr/share/pyshared/apt/progress/gtk2.py:_test()` function showing how to install a package using a GTK front-end.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Austin, you're a star :D

Comment: You probably want to call `cache.open()` after `cache.update()`, in order to utilise the new cache. Otherwise, the old cache will be used which can lead to strange bugs.

Comment: Any way to catch the progress of an install, then do something else once it finishes?

Comment: You can deal with the progress of the un/install operation by subclassing InstallProgress, as described here: https://github.com/excid3/python-apt/blob/master/doc/examples/inst.py