# Can Python's PIP handle system libraries?

Tags: python, pip

I know PIP install packages from the Python Package Index. However, sometimes, a package requires a system library to work properly (e.g. `pycrypto` requires the  `zlib-dev` library to be installed). Is there a way to automatically install these dependencies? Or at list enlist them and download them with another package manager like `apt-get`?

Comment: This seems like what you are looking to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537390/how-to-install-a-package-using-the-python-apt-api

Comment: I was thinking something more like `pip install --with-system-libs <package>`.

Comment: each packages dont have such dependencies information and pip dont know every OS out there.

Comment: or you can install (may be old, different name) pycrypto with apt-get

Comment: The thing is, I'm trying to make the application I developed as self contained as possible. And it has happened to my coworkers that when downloading it they've faced those types of errors.