# How do I connect dbus and policykit to my function in python?

Tags: python, dbus, debian-based, polkit

I am making a python  application that has a method needing root privileges. From https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/polkit-apps.html, I found **Example 2. Accessing the Authority via D-Bus** which is the python version of the code below, I executed it and I thought I'd be able to get root privileges after entering my password but I'm still getting "permission denied" on my app. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130187/how-do-i-remove-debian-packages-using-python-apt-api) is the function I'm trying to connect

```
import dbus

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
proxy = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1', '/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority')
authority = dbus.Interface(proxy, dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority')

system_bus_name = bus.get_unique_name()

subject = ('system-bus-name', {'name' : system_bus_name})
action_id = 'org.freedesktop.policykit.exec'
details = {}
flags = 1            # AllowUserInteraction flag
cancellation_id = '' # No cancellation id

result = authority.CheckAuthorization(subject, action_id, details, flags, cancellation_id)

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

In the python code you quoted, does `result` indicate success or failure? If it fails, you need to narrow down the error by first of all finding out what the return values of `bus`, `proxy`, `authority` and `system_bus_name` are. If it succeeds, you need to check how you are using the `result`.

Comment: Well, i think it succeeds as long as the right password is entered. However, I'm still at a lost as I do not know how to use result. I've tried the docs but couldn't come up with anything concrete.

Comment: Here is an example from the [aptdaemon docs](https://pythonhosted.org/aptdaemon/dbus.html#policykit-privileges)