# Detect missing python-gi-cairo in Gtk program with Gtk.DrawingArea

Tags: python, gtk, cairo, pygobject

If you run a simple Gtk.DrawingArea example with python-gi-cairo uninstalled, there is an error on the console:

`TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'`

Unfortunately no exception is thrown - and the draw handler doesn't get called (the error must happen just before this).

Is there any way I can detect this?

I'd like to prompt the user to install `python-gi-cairo`.

Comment: Python2 or Python3 ?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24517783/6150775